# Is there a plugin for multi-select with ordering feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that has similar functions as [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) (the multiple select feature) but with a user-friendly possibility of ordering of values.

Is there any?

**Context:** I want to let my users create their own "speed dial" (a bunch of icons that are links to pages a user uses often; i.e., customizable set of links) and the ordering of icons is important.

Thank you!

Comment: Based on what mark-up? And what have you found, or attempted? As it stands it seems you're asking us to find you a plug-in...

Comment: I'm googling for more than an hour to find something that would help me. There are many approaches and the one with multi select box is simple to program yet easy for users to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of combining Chosen with jQueryUI? Because they are list items, the multiple select feature would work well with the sortable feature of jQueryUI, especially as a grid:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

Comment: You're welcome - let me know how it goes. Sounds like a cool feature.

Comment: I find sortable plugin so great that I made my own set of divs (icons) that can sorted in a user-friendly way. I found Chosen to be a nice select alternative but the final solution would not be as nice as I wanted.